# Persistent postgres on docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, teamcity, docker-compose

getting started with docker I experiment with persistent container storage for my database-container. I thought it would be a simple task to create a postgres-TeamCity instance. However on osx running kitematic & docker-machine there were some problems regarding permissions when referencing the local file system. Using a persistent-container seems to fix that problem.

Trying to run `docker-compose up -d` with the following:

```
teamcitydb:
  image: postgres:9.3
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=teamcity
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
  volumes_from:
    - pgdata
pgdata:
  image: cogniteev/echo
  command: echo 'Data Container for PostgreSQL'
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

seems to work, however how to create the DB-schema as mentioned here? https://hub.docker.com/r/sjoerdmulder/teamcity/ If I execute manually:

```
SETUP_TEAMCITY_SQL="create role teamcity with login password 'teamcity';create database teamcity owner teamcity;"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword

docker run -it --link teamcity_teamcitydb_1:postgres --rm -e "SETUP_TEAMCITY_SQL=$SETUP_TEAMCITY_SQL" -e "PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" postgres bash -c 'exec echo $SETUP_TEAMCITY_SQL |psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U teamcity'
```

I only receive an error that the table / relation already exists. **What is wrong? Is there a possibility to "include" this statement in the ymal file?**

Teamcity is connected to the DB as follows

```
teamcity:
 image: sjoerdmulder/teamcity
 ports:
   - "8111:8111"
 links:
   - teamcitydb
 environment:
   - TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH=/var/lib/teamcity
   - DB_HOSTNAME=db
   - DB_DATABASE=teamcitydb
   - DB_USERNAME=teamcitydb
   - DB_PASSWORD=teamcitydb
 volumes:
   - ./volumes/teamcity:/var/lib/teamcity
```

However when I try to connect at the web-interface **assuming the default path, there seems to be no connection albeit the link** (see above).

```
Could not connect to PostgreSQL server.
connection refused. check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting tcp/ip connections.
SQL exception: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

[image: web Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@1: https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres specifies how to extend the image --> custom dockerfile which adds some initialization.sql

@2: use the docker-machine ip here

sample docker-compose.yml here: https://github.com/dataplayground/tc/blob/master/docker-compose.yml